# Connection times out in browser after Composer Rest Server starts

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying out setup , development of **Hyperledger Composer** as per the docs 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

I have started the composer rest server  at port 3500

The server starts and webserver listens at http://localhost:3500

Rest api  at http://localhost:3500/explorer

However when i try to access this link in a browser it times out . Firefox and Chrome says connection timed out

Stuck here . Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution . I was not using Hlfv1 connection profile for the network . 
Switched to hlfv1 profile and it worked .